Skeptical Proof of Functional Equations Question
Question: The function $f$ assigns to each non-negative integer $n$, the non-negative integer $f(n)$, such that:
$f(mn) = f(n) + f(m)$ for $m,n \geq 0$
$f(n) = 0$ if the unit digit of $n$ is 3
$f(10) = 0$
Find $f(1985)$
One of my friends saw this question and wrote down a few sentences as below and shared it to me. The below is his reasoning.
His Solution:
$f(1985 \times 0) = f(10 \times 0)$
$f(1985) + f(0) = f(10) + f(0)$
$f(1985) = f(10) = 0$
Issue:
I solved the question the intended way and was surprised to see that his answer matched mine, that $f(1985)$ is indeed 0. I couldn't digest the way he solved it, but wasn't able to find the mistake in this. Is his solution correct? Or am I not intellectual enough to find out the mistake in this?

Yeah, it is pretty clear that for any $n,$ $f(0)=f(0\cdot n)=f(0)+f(n),$ so $f(n)=0.$ All the other conditions are irrelevant. If the problem had been stated about a function of positive integers, you might get something interesting.

Even condition $1$ is stated without including the zero case, you can still show $f$ is zero function, but except $f(0)$.
First, condition $2$ gives you every prime $p\ne2,5$, $f(p)=0$. This is because any prime not equal to $2,5$ must be end with unit digit $1,3,7,9$, except $3$, correspondingly you can multiply the prime by $3,9,7$, then all of them will be end at unit digit $3$. So $f(p)=0$.
Then how to deal with $f(2),f(5)$? Well, $f(10)=f(2)+f(5)=0$, but $f$ is nonnegative. So $f(2)=f(5)=0$.
Now apply fundamental theorem of arithmetics on $n>1$, you get $f(n)=\displaystyle\sum^k_{i=1}f(p_i)m_i$ where $n=\displaystyle\prod^k_{i=1}p_i^{m_i}$ for distinct prime $p_i$ and $m_i\in\mathbb{N}$. But $f$ vanishes at every prime. So $f(n)=0$.
The remaining case becomes finding $f(1)$, but this is easy as by condition $1$, you get $f(1)=0$.
